# Running user input PHP validation results in empty SESSION array

Tags: php, validation, session, shopping-cart

I’m doing a simple shopping cart. I’m not sure how to describe my issue. I have two pages. 1st has checkboxes next to each item. 2nd create an empty array into a SESSION then in a loop, pushes all the checked items to the session array and print out the number of items. the 2nd page also has a form for inputing user detail which is validated using PHP and not JS. The issue is when submitting that form the 2nd page is reloaded and session array becomes empty as $_SESSION[‘cart’]=array(); is triggered. submitting the 1st page gives the right result in the 2nd page but these results becomes 0 when submitting the form in the 2nd page. both pages has: session_start(); in the top.

Here is the key pieces of code for 1st page:

```
<form name="form" method="POST" id="form" action="cart.php">
<input type=checkbox name=cart[item1]>
<input type=checkbox name=cart[item2]>…etc
```

2nd page (cart.php):

```
include "Validation.php";
$_SESSION['cart']=array();
if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
    foreach($_POST['cart'] as $checkboxID => $checkboxVal){
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $checkboxID);
    }
}
echo "<p>number of items in the cart = ".sizeof($_SESSION['cart'])."</p>";


<form name="form" method="POST" id="form" action="">
<input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" placeholder="e.g. me@me.com"/>
<input type="submit" class="buttun" name="buy" value="buy"/>
```

3rd page (Validation.php):

```
if (isset($_POST["buy"])){
//some validation code
}
```

Is there a way to tackle this issue? I tried to create the empty array inside the if statement but got bad results. I think using JS validation will solve the issue but prefer php validation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems in your code.

hopefully you are using `session_start();` at the begning else you will lose sessions data when your page reloads/goes to next page.

in part 2, you dont need to declare a variable.

```
if(isset($_POST['cart']) && !isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    foreach($_POST['cart'] as $checkboxID => $checkboxVal)$_SESSION['cart'][$checkboxID]=$checkboxVal;
```

when you want to see if a form has been used, use a hidden input
`<input type='hidden' name='form1' value='1'>`

then later you can use
`if(isset($_POST['form1']))...`

also, `sizeof($_SESSION['cart'])` should be count($_SESSION['cart'])

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. yes I'm using session_start(). I tried to also use it in Validation.php but it says session is already started.I deleted the array and now my code becomes better. if I add "&& !isset($_SESSION['cart'])" it won't work as intended so I deleted and replace array_push but the session is not updating to the new selected checkboxes!

Comment: if I go back to 1st page and uncheck the boxes, it doesn't update SESSION

Comment: instead of !isset try empty($_SESSION['cart'). also you dont want to include Validation.php since you want to go to there after 'buy' button. both the code can be on the same page though, since it is seperated by `if (isset($_POST["buy"]))`

Comment: when you go back to page 1, you have to show the user what they have selected. so for that you would echo the selected values in the form using the values from session. there is a lot you will need to learn to get this form working.

Comment: now session is working fine. I just unset it whenever the user goes back to 1st page. As I want to show error message regarding validation within the 2nd page, I don't want to go to Validation page. Validation.php has header() that directs to 4th page Confirmation.php when the user inputs are all right. I just found that POST handles only one variable which is cart. So when I click on buy, "if(isset($_POST['inCart'])){...}" doesn't execute. If I add "if(isset($_POST['inCart']) || isset($_POST['purchase']) ){..}" I get Undefined index error on $_POST['cart'] :s